# How to filter data in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have got series of data that contains some objects in one array(json file) and it will be shown by react

```
    class App extends React.Component {
     constructor(props){
     super(props);
      this.state = {
       data: [],
           .
           .
           .
    currentPage: 1,
    itemsPerPage: 20,
    value: '',
    startIndex : 0,
    endIndex : 4,
        }}}

[{'id': '5c0b6cd9e1382352759fbc25', 'hotelinfo': {'hotelsearch': {'realname': 'Korston Hotel Moscow'}},{'id': '5c0b6cd9e1382352759fbc24', 'hotelinfo': {'hotelsearch': {'realname': 'Lavanta Hotel'}},{'id': '5c0b6cd9e1382352759fbc28', 'hotelinfo': {'hotelsearch': {'realname': 'Stanpoli Hotel'}}]
```

IS it possible to write something like this **postsql="select * where realname like '%Korston%'"** to filter data to show just this json file?

```
    [{'id': '5c0b6cd9e1382352759fbc25', 'hotelinfo': {'hotelsearch': {'realname': 'Korston Hotel Moscow'}}]
```

Edit :

There is a paging which displays 4 pages by default and show the rest of pages by clicking next button.

```
render() {
const { data, currentPage, itemsPerPage,startIndex,endIndex } = this.state;
const indexOfLastItem = currentPage * itemsPerPage;
const indexOfFirstItem = indexOfLastItem - itemsPerPage;
const currentItems = data.slice(indexOfFirstItem, indexOfLastItem);
const renderHotel = currentItems.sort((a, b) => a.total - b.total).map((item, i) => {
return  <div class="item">
         <span>{item.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname}</span>
     </div>
});
 const pageNumbers = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(data.length / itemsPerPage); i++) {
pageNumbers.push(i);
}

 const renderPageNumbers = pageNumbers.slice(startIndex, endIndex).map(number => {
 return (
 <li className={(this.state.currentPage === number ? 'active ' : '') + 'controls'}
key={number}
id={number}>
 {number}
 </li>
 )});
  return (
  <div>
   <input type="text" value={this.state.value} 
    onChange={this.handleInputChange} class="hotelName" /><span onClick=this.handleSearch} class="searchbtn">search</span>
   {renderHotel}
   <ul id="page-numbers" class="pagenumDef">
     <li onClick={this.decremant} class="nexprev">
     <span class="fa-backward"></span></li>
     {renderPageNumbers}
    <li onClick={this.increment} class="nexprev"><span class="fa-forward"></span></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 )};
```

As you know I have an input(class="hotelName") which user start to type in (e.g user type 'Korston' ) and click a button and new result should just contain the data of hotels those contain 'Korston' name.

```
  handleInputChange(event) {
      this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
   }
  getObj = obj => {
  let newString = [];
  let returnString = "";
  let inputval = this.state.value
   inputval = inputval.toLowerCase()
  .split(' ')
  .map((s) => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1))
  .join(' ');
  const { data } = this.state;

  data.map(item => {
  const checkString = item.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname;
  newString = checkString.split(" ");
  if (newString.includes(inputval)) {
    returnString = checkString;
  }});

return obj.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname === returnString;
}; 
handleSearch = () => {
 const { data } = this.state;
 const filteredItems = data.filter(this.getObj);
 if (filteredItems.length === 0) {
 return false
 }else{
    return this.setState({data : eval(filteredItems)}, () => console.log("ITEMS : ",this.state.data) )
//In this part new data will be replaced by default data and the number of default Items is 400. By filtering in this part console.log show me 100 items.For the text search the filtering will be done among 100 result not 400 result.I want every search be done among 400 items that is my default number of item. 
  }
};
```

Comment: is there anyway you can do this on the back-end?

Comment: Not actually. it must be done in client side.

Comment: i posted my answer. the only reason I asked is because personally I liked to manipulate the data that's sent to the front-end on the back-end as much as possible first then just display that data on the front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where your data is stored but since you are using ReactJS you should store your data in `state`.

Your state should look like this:

```
state = { 
  arrayOfObjs = [
    {'id': '5c0b6cd9e1382352759fbc25', 'hotelinfo': {'hotelsearch': {'realname': 'Korston Hotel Moscow'}},
    {'id': '5c0b6cd9e1382352759fbc24', 'hotelinfo': {'hotelsearch': {'realname': 'Lavanta Hotel'}},
    {'id': '5c0b6cd9e1382352759fbc28', 'hotelinfo': {'hotelsearch': {'realname': 'Stanpoli Hotel'}}
  ],
};
```

Then have a couple of functions. Your filter function that finds the appropriate place to search and the second function gets the result.

//gets result

```
getObj = obj => {
let tmpString;//we will use this in a little bit to store the split array
let checkString = "Korston Hotel Moscow" //you can easily make this more dynamic if you need to
 tmpString = checkString.split(" "); //splits the checkString by the spaces in the string and stores it in tmpString as an array

 if(tmpString.includes("Korston"){
   //you can change "Korston" to a string variable if you have one for userInput 
    return obj.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname === "Korston Hotel Moscow";
  };
```

//filter function

```
filterObj = () => {
    const { arrayObjs } = this.state; //destructure state, create variable called arrayObjs that has same value as the state variable arrayObjs
    const filteredItems = arrayObjs.filter(this.getObj); //filter that array of objs
    console.log(filteredItems); //you can do something else with filterItems obviously 
  };
```

hope this helps.

Note: the includes() method is not compatible with Internet Explorer. You can swap includes() out with indexOf(). The difference here is that you will check to see `if indexOf() !== -1` if indexOf() returns -1 that means it *does not include it*.

### EDIT

This edit makes the result that is returned more dynamic instead of static. Right now, it will always return "Korston Hotel Moscow" regardless of the search.

Now, it will return the appropriate result depending on the input.

**Dynamic Return**

Change your getObj method to this:

```
getObj = obj => {
    let newString = [];
    let returnString = "";
    const { arrayObjs, userInput } = this.state;

    arrayObjs.map(item => {
      const checkString = item.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname;
      newString = checkString.split(" ");
      if (newString.includes(userInput)) {
        returnString = checkString;
      }
    });
    return obj.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname === returnString;
  };
```

The difference here is the map function. The logic behind this is: you want to check every element or object in that array and search for the `userInput`. When you get the appropriate result then set this local variable `returnString` equal to the `realname` of the `hotelsearch` of the `hotelinfo` of the obj that it matched (this is what `checkString` is). Once you are done mapping, it returns the matched value back to `filterObj`.

All together, your `getObj` and `filterObj` should look like this:

```
  getObj = obj => {
    let newString = [];
    let returnString = "";
    const { arrayObjs, userInput } = this.state;

    arrayObjs.map(item => {
      const checkString = item.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname;
      newString = checkString.split(" ");
      if (newString.includes(userInput)) {
        returnString = checkString;
      }
    });
    return obj.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname === returnString;
  };

  filterObj = () => {
    const { arrayObjs } = this.state;
    const filteredItems = arrayObjs.filter(this.getObj);
    if (filteredItems.length === 0) {
      //do something if there isn't a match
      alert("sorry there are no results for that search");
    }else{
      //do something with the matching results
      //you can add this to your state by using setState or whatever 
      //you want to do with it
    }
  };
```

Comment: Thank you Bens Steves.It workes greatly, but in my issue i have an input which user start to type in (e.g user type 'Korston' ) and click a button and new result should just contain the data of hotels those contain 'Korston' name.Your answer works when user type whole the name (e.g 'Korston Hotel Moscow') but if user type just 'Korston' there is no result.Is there any solution for it?

Comment: hmm....I'm sure if this is efficient but you could split Korston Hotel Moscow and then check to see if that split array contains user input...does that makes sense? I can update my answer if you need to see it

Comment: Yes, exactly true. I would be grateful if you could update your answer.

Comment: getObj = obj => {
    let inputval = this.state.value
    let tmpString;
    let checkString = obj.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname 
     tmpString = checkString.split(" "); 
     if(tmpString.includes(inputval)){
     // return obj.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname === "Korston Hotel Moscow";
   console.log('ok')
  }else{
    console.log('nok')
  }
  };

Comment: 'inputval' is the text typed by user

Comment: And i didn't get this line: return obj.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname === "Korston Hotel Moscow"

Comment: Should  I put 'inputval ' in this line obj.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname === "Korston Hotel Moscow" instead of 'Korston Hotel Moscow' ?

Comment: your input value would be passed to includes. Put it here tmpString.includes(inputval).  the line you are referring returns that string. So if you want to return just "Korston" or the input val then yes you can put that there. But if you want the user to let's say search for Korston and the result that is returned is "Korston Hotel Moscow" then leave that as is. Makes sense? lmk if it doesn't. Happy to help :)

Comment: Thanks a lot  Bens Steves. My problem has been solved, but there is another issue. When the user start tying 'Korston'  the result shows the information of 'Korston Hotel Moscow' , then the user types 'Lavanta'. I expect the result shows the information of 'Lavanta Hotel' but seems when ever user types a text(e.g Korston) for the next time the filtering will be done in previoue result not the default result. sorry for may bad explanation .Does it make sense?

Comment: i believe that makes sense. you want the "Korston Hotel Moscow" or the value you're returning to be more dynamic not static. See my edit in the answer and lmk if that helps :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bens Steves for your help :)

Comment: Hi @Bens Steves. I'm sorry but I think I couldn't explain it more understandable. Foe example we have 100 results by default.The user types a name,he  will see 20 results of the search.For the text search the filtering will be done among 20 result not 100 result :|

Comment: Thanks @Bens Steves for your support.  Is it possible for you to look at my code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [underscore js](https://underscorejs.org/) to solve the issue, the `filterArray` method requires two parameter, first is array of object and second is the query you need to search

```js
var arr =[
  {
    "id": "5c0b6cd9e1382352759fbc25",
    "hotelinfo": {
      "hotelsearch": {
        "realname": "Korston Hotel Moscow"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "5c0b6cd9e1382352759fbc24",
    "hotelinfo": {
      "hotelsearch": {
        "realname": "Lavanta Hotel"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "5c0b6cd9e1382352759fbc28",
    "hotelinfo": {
      "hotelsearch": {
        "realname": "Stanpoli Hotel"
      }
    }
  }
]
  
  
  function filterArray(arr, query){
    return _.filter(arr,function(obj){
       return obj.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname.indexOf(query) >-1
    })
  }
  
  var result = filterArray(arr,'Korston');
  console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Hope it helps.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The filter funtion for Array object will work for you.It will output the item in Array which satisfies the condition.

```
let result = this.state.data.filter((item) => {
   item.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname === 'Korston Hotel Moscow'
})
console.log(result)
```

---

Edit:

```
let result = this.state.data.filter((item) => {
    let realname = item.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname.toString
    if (realname.indexOf(inputval.toString) !== -1){
       return true
    } else {
       return false
    }
})
console.log(result)
```

Or

```
let result = this.state.data.filter((item) => {
        let realname = item.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname.toString
        if (realname.search(inputval.toString) !== -1){
           return true
        } else {
           return false
        }
    })
    console.log(result)
```

---

#### Edit2:

About your problem:when user typed any word of 'Korston Hotel Moscow' (e.g 'Moscow' or 'Hotel' or 'Korston' ) .I suggest that after checking, set the inputVal value.

In the place of

```
console.log('ok')
```

change to the below

```
console.log('ok')
this.setState({
   value: item.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname
},() => this.state.value)
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer,but actually in my issue i have an input which user start to type in (e.g user type 'Korston' )  and click a button and new result should just contain the  data of hotels those contain 'Korston' name.

Comment: handelSearch(event){
let inputval = this.state.value
let result = this.state.data.filter((item) => {
    if ( item.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname === 'inputval'){
        console.log('ok')
    }else{
        console.log('nok')
    }
  
})

Comment: the above code is on click function for searching data according the text which user type in input text

Comment: inputval is the value of input typed by user

Comment: when ever i click the button console.log  is  = nok

Comment: it should be item.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname === inputval,not item.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname === 'inputval'

Comment: Thanks Root, You help me a lot, but if the user type 'Korston' instead of 'Korston Hotel Moscow' there would not be any result.

Comment: You mean that in this.state.data is 'Korston Hotel Moscow' and the inputval is  'Korston',and you want it has result.Or this.state.data is 'Korston' ,inputval want to match 'Korston',but failed.

Comment: I mean that in this.state.data is 'Korston Hotel Moscow' and the inputval is 'Korston' and i want it has result.Such as like '%Korston%'" in postsql. Every item.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname that is like Korston should be shown.

Comment: I have edited my answer.Use search or indexOf  function for string object works for your request.@bita

Comment: Thanks , but there is this error : realname.indexOf is not a function

Comment: use typeof realname to check the type of realname,if it's not string, use toString to make it be string.The indexOf function only be useful for string object.

Comment: check whether realname has value before, if (realname.length !=== 0){....indexOf}.I guess when realname is empty, the problem comes out.@bita

Comment: let result = this.state.data.filter((item) => {
        let realname = item.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname
        let len = realname.length 
         if (len !== 0){
           if (realname.search(inputval.toString) !== -1){
            console.log('ok')
                return true
              } else {
                console.log('nok')
              return false
         }
         }
    })

Comment: but when ever I type any thing , console.log is 'nok'

Comment: I'm terribly sorry Root. It works but user wants when ever is typing any word of 'Korston Hotel Moscow' (e.g 'Moscow' or 'Hotel' or 'Korston' ) shows the result of 'Korston Hotel Moscow' and it must not be case sensitive. It should not be any different between 'Hotel' or 'hotel'.

Comment: Add str.toLowerCase() to change all the string to lower letter before search()@bita

Comment: Thank. but what about this one: " when user  typed any word of 'Korston Hotel Moscow' (e.g 'Moscow' or 'Hotel' or 'Korston' ) shows the result of 'Korston Hotel Moscow' "

Comment: I have changed my answer.@bita